# How to disable a strange white circle around the cursor in UV editing mode?

Tags: uv

How to disable a strange white circle around the cursor in UV editing mode? it is distorting  everything once I try to move or rotate a UV island. It sometimes moves all of them at once, despite the fact that only one of them is selected (red). Also I have the impression, that all the UV islands are distorted as if they were fitted onto a globe. I must have accidentally switched something. I never had such a strange problem and I haven't come across anything like this on the Net. I would really appreciate your help, since the way it is now it's absolutely impossible to work:) I am rather new to Blender, I am mostly unwrapping couches and sofas.

Answer (score 3):

You might have proportional editing enabled. This can be toggled with <kbd>O</kbd>

It can also be found under *Mesh* > *Proportional Editing*

Comment: @Kas Make sure you accept his answer!

Comment: Shift+O won't toggle Proportianal Editing, it just switches PE fallofs.

Comment: @MrZak Ah, sorry. I was just reading that off a wiki page. I'll change it.

Comment: @Kas please Mark this answer as Accepted (The green Checkmark under the upvote/downvote buttons) so this case can be marked as resolved.